# How to require all network activity to pass a KVM guest firewall before reaching the host?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, firewall, linux-networking

Most of the information I've come across tends to set up a KVM firewall using a bridge connection.

From my understanding it is a security risk if network traffic can reach the host without having to pass the firewall first.

I've seen the main NIC (e.g. `eth0`) be set as the virtual machine NIC however does this exclude the host from accessing `eth0`?

The other option which comes to mind is a PCI passthrough of the NIC however I have run into problems with the method.

Are there any other approaches to requiring host traffic to go through the firewall first? What method do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is to separate which interfaces are used to add network access to VMs and which are used to control host. Often third set of interfaces is used to access VM images on some kind of network shared storage. So you ideally have 6 interfaces: 4 of Gigabit Ethernet and 2 of Ten Gigiabit Ethernet.

Second idea is that you could use different 802.1q VLANs for host and for virtual machines. I had built a network where we had VMs in three different VLANs, and sometimes one VM could have participation in several VLANs (by creating several virtual NICs and bridging them with several different VLANs on the host)

Note server hadrware ofter have a BMC, which is used to out-of-band control of host. Essentially this is a small computer that has access to host computer's sensors, it could see values (temperature, fan rpms), power on/off/reset host as if you push button, even has IP KVM functionality and so on, and it has network address on its own. It also usually implements IPMI protocol. It is exposed often as shared with LAN1 (i.e. like a small switch, not quite switch - host and BMC could not communicate, but both of them commuticate with external devices) or independent ethernet jack which is routed to BMC exclusively. Blade systems could have one or two (redundant) BMC per cage, not in each blade server.

Secure setup looks like this:

bond0 is (eth0, eth1) combined by LACP, it has an IP address in the host and is used to control host.

bond1 is (eth2, eth3) combined by LACP. It is split with vlans, i.e. host has bond1.10, bond1.552 virtual subinterfaces etc.
There are bridges created: br10 bridges bond1.10 and all VM host-side interfaces for VMs which participate in vlan 10, br552 bridges bond1.552 and all VM host-side for vlan 522 and so on. Neither of these interfaces has an IP address, so VMs couldn't communicate with the host.

bond2 is (eth4, eth5) combined and used to access VM disk images via iSCSI, CEPH, to sync DRBD and so on. It has an IP in host, but is connected to completely separated storage network with its special requirements.

bond0 and bond1 are recommended to be separate physically, for VMs to be unable not only communicate with the host, but even to saturate host's control network. That network is used for example to transfer memory contents of virtual machine in the event of live migration to other host, and no VM could saturate performance of this process.

Even if you are building just small system with one physical interface to host five virtual machines and have to combine functionality of bond0 and bond1, you could have IP address only on physical interface (accessible as as default/native vlan) and subinterfaces participating in bridges with VM host-side adaptors, all tagged. Still VMs couldn't directly access host, and intelligent L2 switch and a separate firewall device or L3 switch alone could do inter-vlan routing and traffic filtering.

Comment: To prevent the host from (accidentally or intentionally) communicating through the br10 and br552 interfaces, are there any additional measures that can be taken beyond just not assigning IP addresses to those interfaces?  That's the thing that makes the bridging approach seem iffy:  the host *has* a connection to the VM network, even if it's not *using* it.

Comment: The fact host itself has a complete access to the VM memory and disk is not a concern for you, but capability to have access VM network is a big deal? Yes, in virtualization you have to trust your host. You shouldn't trust VMs.

Comment: An important remark. In properly designed system host shouldn't run any services not related directly to supporting virtualization. I.e. for example, it is bad to serve public web sites there or run application database or so on. Web server is allowed, but only for host control. Database could be, again, if only virtualization system makes use of it, and nobody else. This way you could keep host secure. Any customer service should be run in virtual machines.

Comment: Well, the "intentionally" part is less of a concern since the host is trusted.  But "accidentally" is a risk.  And when the VM is running a firewall, you want the host to have as little exposure as possible to the untrusted network.  It has to process enough of the Ethernet frame to do the bridging, of course, but it'd be nice to have it completely ignore the payload.  The host will still receive ARP requests, for example, and might parse them before checking against the interface's (empty) list of IPs.

Comment: Now I think I understand what do you want. So primary best practice is to lower risk by not having public services on host. You could disable arp on bridge interfaces. You could implement firewall on that interfaces, as suggested by other answer. I've never seen a system configured with the firewall. You could also implement openvswitch, I don't know much about its security, but it definitely has an ability to forbid communication of host with thуse networks.

Comment: Can you disable arp on bridge interfaces for the host only without affecting the VMs? That is, by disabling arp on the bridge, wouldn't you also be disabling arp on for the VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Since a Linux bridge creates a corresponding network interface (e.g. `br0`) on the host, I don't think there's a way to make the bridge completely inaccessible from the host OS.  With your firewall VM running, `brctl show` will tell you that the interfaces `eth0` and `vnet0` are attached to it, but it's actually acting like a *three*-port switch:  one port goes to `eth0`, one goes to `vnet0` (the VM), and one goes to the `br0` interface on the host.

You could probably set up some [ebtables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/) rules to block all frames going to or from the host's `br0` interface.  That may be the best approach, but I don't know enough about ebtables to provide any details on how to do it.

Another option is to just not configure any IP addresses on the bridge interface, which should prevent normal applications from communicating through it.  It'll still be accessible to applications like Wireshark with root privileges (and this might come in handy).

In Debian-based systems (such as Ubuntu), you can put the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
```

The "manual" means "don't assign any addresses when bringing the interface up"; it's meant for setups where something else will assign an address later, but it also works when you just don't want an address at all.

The one exception is an IPv6 link-local address, which is assigned automatically by the kernel rather than by the distribution's networking setup scripts, so you get one even with the "manual" setting.  You can avoid that by disabling IPv6 entirely on the interface.  Create a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` and put this in it:

```
net.ipv6.conf.br0.disable_ipv6=1
```

(It'd be nice if you could entirely disable IPv4 on the interface too, but there's no corresponding option for that.)